# jquery mobile navbar with two buttons per row

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navbar

I have a jquery mobile navbar that can have anything from 2 to 8 buttons..  I do not like that jquery mobile bundles into a single row when there ,= 5 butons..
What I want is to force that the navbar is 2 buttons at a time..

Has anyone else done it??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a combination of [content-grids](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html) and a navbar?

```
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a"> 
            <h1>Example grid</h1> 

            <div data-role="navbar">
                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">Block A</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">Block B</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-a">Block A</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">Block B</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-a">Block A</div>

                </div><!-- /grid-b -->
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div> <!-- /header -->
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle with this code - Doesn't look right to me: http://jsfiddle.net/pFMXL/

Comment: @AdamD I'm not entirely sure what the question is asking for, this displays rows of 2 in your fiddle as I expected.  Are you interpreting the question as "only display two buttons at any given time?"

Comment: He's wanting to display buttons in a navbar, not text in content boxes.

Comment: What I want is the navbar control to layout the items for me without need for me to do it manually, some thing like 
<div data-role="navbar" data-columns="2"> and have it layout items 2 per row..   I can do it manually like your examples, but 1)I do not know how many items I will have, and I am using data binding.. so don't want to cloud the code with the extra layout..  This seems like a valid request for navbar, no??

Comment: If I have nothing better, since I really don't want to tweak the jquery layout what I think I will do is this.... http://jsfiddle.net/pjYRL/  --- what I am doing there is populating enough "dummy, hidden" LIs for jquery to have six, that way I get the layout I want.. without tweaking jquery code.

Comment: @JaimeRodriguezCarrete could you not use a bit of client side templating to build the navbar for you?  A simple bit of underscore.js or handlebars?  I can put an example together if that sounds like an appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div data-role='navbar' data-grid='a'>
    <ul>
        <li><a>bt1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>bt2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role='navbar' data-grid='a'>
    <ul>
        <li><a>bt3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>bt4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role='navbar' data-grid='a'>
    <ul>
        <li><a>bt5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>bt6</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role='navbar' data-grid='a'>
    <ul>
        <li><a>bt7</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>bt8</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi A. Magalhaes, this is not the same.. because I now end up having to reset selections on the other appbars when it happens on any since they are not mutually exclusive...  
These are good suggestions but not quite the same..   

Thanks for the suggestions